# Access struct from other class

Tags: ios, swift, struct

I have following class with struct:

```
class JsonHelper {

    //for tests only
    struct arrivalScan {
        let TOID: String
        let UserId: String
        let GateId: String
        let TimeStamp: String
    }


    func sendArrival(scan: arrivalScan){
      //do something
    }

}
```

In my view controller I am trying to create initialise arrivalScan:

```
let scan = JsonHelper.arrivalScan.init(TOID:"D/0098/123456",UserId:"O0124553",GateId: "G/0098/536371",TimeStamp: "11/04/2018 11:51:00")
```

and then pass this as argument to the `sendArrival` function in `JsonHelper`

```
JsonHelper.sendArrival(scan)
```

But getting error 'JsonHelper.arrivalScan' is not convertible to 'JsonHelper'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should avoid using `init` directly. `JsonHelper.arrivalScan(TOID:...` will be good enough.

Comment: Any specific reason as to why to avoid using init directly? @Ryan

Comment: @BadhanGanesh Because you don't need. You don't want to type couple more characters every time, do you? If you are using swiftlint like script tool, saving characters in a line can be a big issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issues:

1. First, always name your classes and structs with an initial capital letter. `arrivalScan` should be `ArrivalScan`. This will help you differentiate between a class (or struct) and an instance.
2. The `sendArrival` function is an instance function. You are trying to access it as if it were a class function. Create an instance of the JsonHelper class, then call the function on that instance.
3. Variable names inside your struct should begin with lowercase.

Example:

```
class JsonHelper {

    struct ArrivalScan {
        let toId: String
        let userId: String
        let gateId: String
        let timestamp: String
    }

    func sendArrival(scan: ArrivalScan) {
        //do something
    }

}

let helper = JsonHelper()
let scan = JsonHelper.ArrivalScan(toId: "value", userId: "value", gateId: "value", timestamp: "value")

helper.sendArrival(scan: scan)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should call this method like below,

```
JsonHelper().sendArrival(scan: scan)
```

Because `sendArrival` is not a `static/class` method so it should be accessed by calling initializer and also you were missing the parameter name `scane:`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you are trying to call `sendArrival` directly from the class itself without creating an instance from it. So you have two choices to solve the issue:

**1-** Declare `sendArrival` emthod as *static*:

```
static func sendArrival(scan: arrivalScan){
    //do something
}
```

thus:

```
JsonHelper.sendArrival(scan: scan)
```

**2-** Create an instance from `JsonHelper` and call the method using it:

```
let scan = JsonHelper.arrivalScan.init(TOID:"D/0098/123456",UserId:"O0124553",GateId: "G/0098/536371",TimeStamp: "11/04/2018 11:51:00")
let jsonHelperObject = JsonHelper()

jsonHelperObject.sendArrival(scan: scan)
```

Choosing one of the solutions depends on what is the appropriate design of `JsonHelper` class.

---

*Aside bar notes:*

- As naming convention, naming a structure should follow the upper camel case, which means `ArrivalScan` instead of `arrivalScan`.
- When calling the `sendArrival` method, you have to mention the label, as: `sendArrival(scan: scan)` instead of `sendArrival(scan) // compile-time error`. If you want to call it without mentioning the label, you could declare it as `func sendArrival(_ scan: arrivalScan)` therefore you would be able to call it as `sendArrival(scan)`.
- You could instantiate `scan` as `let scan = JsonHelper.arrivalScan(TOID:"D/0098/123456",UserId:"O0124553",GateId: "G/0098/536371",TimeStamp: "11/04/2018 11:51:00")`, without the need of `.init(...`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of your `JsonHelper` class to be able to call the `sendArrival()`  method and thus solve your error:

```
let jsonHelper = JsonHelper()
jsonHelper.sendArrival(scan)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or mark `sendArrival` function as static.